# Same viewbag value in multiple views

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

So I have a search bar in my `_Layout.cshtml` file that requires a list of all the categories to be able to filter.

The problem is that I am putting my category list in the view bag and have to do

```
List<categories> categories = db.categories.ToList();
ViewBag.categories = categories;
```

in each view even in those that won't have use of this list.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

It's a little unclear what problem you're trying to solve, but if the `_Layout.cshtml` needs the value you're going to need to pass it from every controller or you risk exceptions at run-time because the ViewBag is empty.

One solution is to create a base class controller and override the `OnResultExecuting` method.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // In case you're doing any AJAX calls there's no sense in
        // incurring the overhead of filling the ViewBag.
        if(!Request.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            List<categories> categories = db.categories.ToList();
            ViewBag.categories = categories;
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Now just make sure every controller in your application inherits from `BaseController`.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use sessions if you want to pass data from multiple controllers?

Sessions

Session is the way to persist the data till the current session is alive. If we need some data to be accessible from multiple controllers, actions and views then Session is the way to store and retrieve the data
•Session data never expires.

Example is described below

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Customer Obj = new Customer();

        Obj.Name = "Sourav ";

        Obj.Surname = "Kayal";

        Session["Customer"] = Obj;
        return View();
    }

}
}

Create a view to display data
```

As we are using MVC3 application, we are allowed to create Razor view. create a razor view like below to access session data.

```
@{
Layout = null;
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    @{
        var CustomerInfo = (MVC3.Models.Customer) Session["Customer"];
    }

    Customer Name is :- @CustomerInfo.Name;
    <br />

    Customer Surname is :-@CustomerInfo.Surname;
</div>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be accessing `Session` from within the View. If you're trying to avoid the overhead of retrieving the data each time a global caching mechanism would make much more sense than taking up memory in each user's session for the exact same dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how I got around it:

I made a separate controller method and view for that section and called the `@Html.Action("SearchBar", "Home")` and put that in the `_Layout.cshtml` file.

Each time that 'section' is rendered its controller method gets called and the data fetched.